# jQuery UI datepicker - disable public holidays, weekends, next day after 10am AND only allow Tuesday, Wednesday & Thursday as selectable days

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

I'm using the code from [JQuery UI Datepicker Disbale Next Day After 12pm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17526592/jquery-ui-datepicker-disbale-next-day-after-12pm) to disable weekends, public holidays and next day (if selected after 10am), but I'm stuck on how to only allow Tuesday, Wednesday and Thursday to be selected.

```
// dates
var dateMin = new Date();
var weekDays = AddWeekDays(1);
dateMin.setDate(dateMin.getDate() + weekDays);
var natDays = [
  [1, 1, 'uk'],
  [12, 25, 'uk'],
  [12, 26, 'uk']
];
function noWeekendsOrHolidays(date) {
    var noWeekend = $j.datepicker.noWeekends(date);
    if (noWeekend[0]) {
        return nationalDays(date);
    } else {
        return noWeekend;
    }
}
function nationalDays(date) {
    for (i = 0; i < natDays.length; i++) {
        if (date.getMonth() == natDays[i][0] - 1 && date.getDate() == natDays[i][1]) {
            return [false, natDays[i][2] + '_day'];
        }
    }
    return [true, ''];
}
function AddWeekDays(weekDaysToAdd) {
    var mydate = new Date();
    if (mydate.getHours()>=10) 
    var daysToAdd = 1;
    else var daysToAdd = 0;
    var day = mydate.getDay()
    weekDaysToAdd = weekDaysToAdd - (5 - day)
    if ((5 - day) < weekDaysToAdd || weekDaysToAdd == 1) {
        daysToAdd = (5 - day) + 2 + daysToAdd
    } else { // (5-day) >= weekDaysToAdd
        daysToAdd = (5 - day) + daysToAdd
    }
    while (weekDaysToAdd != 0) {
        var week = weekDaysToAdd - 5
        if (week > 0) {
            daysToAdd = 7 + daysToAdd
            weekDaysToAdd = weekDaysToAdd - 5
        } else { // week < 0
            daysToAdd = (5 + week) + daysToAdd
            weekDaysToAdd = weekDaysToAdd - (5 + week)
        }
    }

    return daysToAdd;
}   

$j('.input-text.addon.addon-custom').datepicker({
    beforeShowDay: noWeekendsOrHolidays,
    minDate : dateMin,
    defaultDate: +1,
    firstDay: 1,
    changeFirstDay: true,
    dateFormat: "DD, dd MM yy"
});
```

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/prydonian/4k4gga6j/

Answer (score 0):

On your datepicker function, add the "[beforeShowDay](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-beforeShowDay)" option like this.

```
jQuery('#datepicker').datepicker({
    minDate: dateMin,
    defaultDate: +1,
    firstDay: 1,
    changeFirstDay: true,
    dateFormat: "DD, dd MM yy",
    beforeShowDay: function(day){
         if (day.getDay()<2 || day.getDay()>4){
            return [false, ""];
        }
        return noWeekendsOrHolidays(day);
    }
});
```

here is the Fiddle updated: http://jsfiddle.net/4k4gga6j/3/

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you right, you need to exclude any day other than Tuesday, Wednesday and Thursday? If the answer is yes, then you should add the following code to your existing noWeekendsOrHolidays method:

```
($.inArray(date.getDay(), [2, 3, 4]) != -1)
```

here is updated jsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/4k4gga6j/4/